# 3-ех уровнии суб меню на jquery

Tags: jquery, меню, javascript

Здравствуйте!
Хотел сделать 3-ех уровнии меню.

```
<ul id="ldd_menu" class="ldd_menu">
                <li>
                    <span>Главная</span><!-- Increases to 510px in width-->
                    <div class="ldd_submenu">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">South America</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Antartica</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Africa</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Asia and Australia</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Europe</a></li>
                        </ul>   
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

Имеется такое меню. Как можно сделать с этого подменю нападобе вот этого [ссылка](http://apycom.com/menus/9-deep-sky-blue.html)

вот код javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                /**
                 * the menu
                 */
                var $menu = $('#ldd_menu');

                /**
                 * for each list element,
                 * we show the submenu when hovering and
                 * expand the span element (title) to 510px
                 */
                $menu.children('li').each(function(){
                    var $this = $(this);
                    var $span = $this.children('span');
                    $span.data('width',$span.width());

                    $this.bind('mouseenter',function(){
                        $menu.find('.ldd_submenu').stop(true,true).hide();
                        $span.stop().animate({'width':'200px'},300,function(){
                            $this.find('.ldd_submenu').slideDown(300);
                        });
                    }).bind('mouseleave',function(){
                        $this.find('.ldd_submenu').stop(true,true).hide();
                        $span.stop().animate({'width':$span.data('width')+'px'},300);
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
```